# (python) SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

I am trying to compile the following code but I have this message of syntax error. I can't understand why exactly and how to solve it. Can you help me please?

The code

````
def powerset(iterable):
    """powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"""
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(2, 5))


def find_key_of_table(data: pd.DataFrame) -> List:
    power_set = powerset(data)
    n = len(data.index)
    result_list = []
    for s in power_set:
        if len(data[list(s)].drop_duplicates().index) == n:
                result_list.append(s)
    return result_list
------------------------------------------------------------------------
The error:

File "feature_selection.py", line 33
    def find_key_of_table(data: pd.DataFrame) -> List:
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```
````

Comment: Old Python version (<3.5)?

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: Python version 2.7.5 @user8408080

Comment: @Daniel your Python version is way too old for type annotations. You should not use Python 2 for any project, because it has not been officially supported for quite a while now. You'll need at least Python 3.5 for type hints, as Klaus said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to python version. After using python 3.7 to compile and run, the issue was solved. Thank you a lot for the help guys :)